# How to match a key starting with -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to match a key which is in the following format in Perl language.

```
Format => 'Password key1 key2'

key1   =>  Alphanumeric text (ABCD1234)

key2 => -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----ABCDEFG\nasdafasfas\n\safaf\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I am not able to match this format with my regular expression.

I have tried matching the keyword 'Password' then key1 but I am not able to match the key2 starting with hyphens.

```
^\s*Password\s+(\S+)\s+(-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----(\S+)-----END PRIVATE KEY-----)\s*$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `\S+` only matches one or more non-whitespace chars while you have line breaks in there. Replace it with `((?s:.*?))` (or with `(.*?)` and add `s` modifier after the `/` ending regex delimiter) and make sure the text is not read in line by line.

Comment: Does key2 contain line feeds (despite what you showed), or does it contain the two characters `\` and `n` as shown?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the /m and /s switch. When /m is turned on $ will match at newline and since you have "\n" in key2 using $ will fail the match. You can match still end of the string with just (.+) or anchor it using \Z.

Check this out:

```
$ export a="Password ABCD1234 -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----ABCDEFG\nasdafasfas\n\safaf\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"
$ echo $a | perl -0777 -ne ' /^\s*Password\s+(\S+)\s+(-+BEGIN.+)/ms and print "key1=$1\nkey2=$2" '
key1=ABCD1234
key2=-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----ABCDEFG
asdafasfas
\safaf
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
$ echo $a | perl -0777 -ne ' /^\s*Password\s+(\S+)\s+(-+BEGIN.+)\Z/ms and print "key1=$1\nkey2=$2" '
key1=ABCD1234
key2=-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----ABCDEFG
asdafasfas
\safaf
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
$
```